# Will you clarify the difference between 2 (seemingly equivalent) pieces of code

Tags: javascript, promise, fetch

I am learning to use fetch and thought I was comfortable with promises but in the following code I don't understand why there have to be 2 `.then()`'s.

```
function getInput() {
    fetch(url)
        .then((res1) => {
            return res1.json();
        })
        .then((res2) => {
            console.log(res2.results);
        });
}
```

Now, to my understanding res1 should be a data blob but if I `console.log(res1.json());` it comes back as a promise. Shouldn't the promise be resolved at that point? Why the need for the extra `.then()`?

In other words, why doesn't this work:

```
function getInput() {
    fetch(url)
        .then((res) => {
            console.log(res.json().results);
        });
}
```

It prints `undefined` where I would expect it to produce the same output as the previous code

Comment: `.json()` returns a new promise since its an async operation.

Comment: the simply answer is it comes down to scopes of responsibility within an asynchronous workflow.